# compare the header of dataframes and check if they are same

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames  both having approx. more than 300 column and i want to validate dynamically if the names are different and create a data frame of with two mutated column showing different names or matching.

do we have any other solution for this...??

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),ncol=11))
colnames(df1) <- c("mpg","cyl","lka","mnp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb")
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),ncol=13))
colnames(df2) <- c("mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","ljh","qsec","vs","ring","gear","carb","jun","owa")

df1 <- rbind(names(df1), df1)
df2 <- rbind(names(df2), df2)

t1 <- merge(data.frame(df1, row.names=NULL), data.frame(df2, row.names=NULL), 
            by = 0, all = TRUE)[-1]
```

The output required should be :

[image]

Comment: Suggest you try using the '%in%' function here - e.g. names(df1) %in% names(df2) will return a Boolean vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try using this -

```
library(dplyr)

n1 <- names(df1)
n2 <- names(df2)
n <- max(length(n1), length(n2))

bind_rows(df1 = n1[1:n], df2 = n2[1:n]) %>%
  mutate(names_df1 = ifelse(df1 %in% df2, 'avialable in df2', 'Not available in df1'), 
         names_df2 = ifelse(df2 %in% df1, 'avialable in df1', 'Not available in df2'))

#    df1   df2   names_df1            names_df2           
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>                <chr>               
# 1 mpg   mpg   avialable in df2     avialable in df1    
# 2 cyl   cyl   avialable in df2     avialable in df1    
# 3 lka   disp  Not available in df1 Not available in df2
# 4 mnp   hp    Not available in df1 Not available in df2
# 5 drat  drat  avialable in df2     avialable in df1    
# 6 wt    ljh   Not available in df1 Not available in df2
# 7 qsec  qsec  avialable in df2     avialable in df1    
# 8 vs    vs    avialable in df2     avialable in df1    
# 9 am    ring  Not available in df1 Not available in df2
#10 gear  gear  avialable in df2     avialable in df1    
#11 carb  carb  avialable in df2     avialable in df1    
#12 NA    jun   Not available in df1 Not available in df2
#13 NA    owa   Not available in df1 Not available in df2
```